# BizTalk 2020 registered adapters through Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, adapter, biztalk, biztalk-2020

When I put in the BizTalk SQL Server and Database details nothing comes up under the list of registered adapters.  The database does auto populate from the SQL Server name though.

When I check the list of adapters on the BizTalk server there are multiple listed including the WCF-SQL that I'm trying to use.

Can anyone advise why nothing is coming up?

[image: Adapter Wizard Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install both the 64 and 32 bit version of the adapter. The BizTalk Admin console needs the 32 bit, most everything else needs the 64 bit.